# como generar una consulta SQL que agrupe por tipo de elementos en una fila

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, poo, data

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta

existen 2 tablas A y B ambas se relacionan por el ID. pero B tienen una columna llamada estados.

A (id, muchos_otros_campos)
B (id, a_id, muchos_otros_campos, state)

Los estados pueden ser múltiples. (nulo, aprobado y no aprobado)

Como hago una consulta que me bote la siguiente tabla:

```
ID, Pagos nulos, Pagos aprobados, pagos no aprobados
1,0,2,0
2,0,0,0
3,1,0,0
```

Hasta el momento he logrado hacer lo siguiente:

```
select a.id, b.state, count(*) from A a left join B b on a.id = b.a_id group by b.state;
```

Comment: Hay varias respuestas en el sitio, temas como "suma o agregación condicional", de cualquier forma la idea sería algo así `select a.id, count(case when b.state='nulo' then 1 else null) as 'nulos' from A a left join B b on a.id = b.id group by a.id`

Comment: Sin un [ejemplo MCV](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) prácticamente nos pides que adivinemos la estructura de las tablas y los datos.

Comment: Ya edito la pregunta. Por que las tablas tienen como 200 campos.

Comment: Ya me funciono: select  pck.id, count(case when rt.state = 'pago aprobado' then 1 else null end) as aprobados from turismoi_co.packages pck left join 
turismoi_co.reservations rt on pck.id = rt.package_id group by pck.id, rt.state; Ahora el problema es que me bota muchas veces el mismo A pero con los campos en 0.